# Numpy how to take one element from each row

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have numpy array `A` of shape `(n,m)`. I want to make an array `b` of shape `(n,)` by choosing one element from each row of `A`. I make a vector of indices `y` of shape `(n,)` and I want to construct `b` so that `b[i] = A[i,y[i]]` for each `i`.

One way I can think to do this is `b = A[np.arange(n), y]`, which does what I want. However, I wonder if there is a more efficient way to do this, because I'm calling this operation in a function which is called many times with different `A`s and don't want python to construct a new copy of `np.arange(n)` every time the function is called.

Comment: Store `np.arange(n)` as an array and reuse?

Comment: You're already using the de facto standard way of doing it.

Comment: `np.choose(y, A.T)` avoids the need for `np.arange(n)` so is more efficient in that respect (but not necessarily faster overall).

Comment: @AlexRiley Yup.. `choose` is sadly going to be far slower and not work at all for arrays with `n` > 31.

Comment: @miradulo: `choose` works fine with `n` > 31 here. In some very simple testing, (integer arrays, various shapes), it takes about twice as long as the indexing method though, which is a shame.

Comment: @AlexRiley Ah oops, I'm used to thinking about dimensions with `m, n` instead of `n, m` - correction is that it won't work with `m` > 31. But yeah, agreed.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simplified answer, but if you can keep around np.arange then that will be faster, but potentially a faster way would be to compute y to match the flatten indexes of A that you want (i.e. y += np.arange(n)*m). The following code times each solution and gives the same output. `*Note: If your arrays are too large then flatten will take some time and keeping arange() array around will be faster`

```
from timeit import timeit

setup = '''
import numpy as np
k = 6
y = np.arange(k)
a = np.arange(k**2).reshape(k,k)
'''

setup2 = '''import numpy as np
k = 6
y = np.arange(k)
a = np.arange(k**2).reshape(k,k)
y += y * k
'''

print "Original:", timeit("b = a[np.arange(k),y]",setup=setup)
print "Keep np.arange around:", timeit("b = a[y,y]",setup=setup)
print "Flatten:", timeit("b = a.flatten()[y]", setup=setup2)
#Original: 1.57689285278
#Keep np.arange around: 0.977301120758
#Flatten: 0.710500001907
```